# Show the row id in alert box of dynamic table right after checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, tablerow

I've researched a lot about this in stackoverflow but none of the solutions work for me..

```
<div class="ibox-content">

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example tdiv" id="resultTable" >  
                                 <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>    
                                        <th>Company Name</th>
                                        <th>Niche</th>
                                        <th>Date Added</th> 
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    @foreach($companies as $company)
                                    <tr class="clickable-row" id="{{$company->id}}">
                                        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="input[]"></td>
                                        <td>{{ $company->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $company->niche }}</td>
                                        <td>{!! date('M j, Y', strtotime($company->created_at)) !!}</td>     
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach


                                </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

My Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#resultTable").click(function(){
  var closestTr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
  alert(closestTr);
  });
</script>
```

Is this because I'm using ibox or something? I dunno what's going on please help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be very simple......

All I needed to do was change the Javascript to the class of the checkbox...

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.i-checks').click(function(event) {
   var companyId = this.id;
   console.log(companyId);
   alert(companyId);
   });
});
```